# Range of values of $k_1$ which satisfies the inequality

Tags: inequality

The core idea is to find the value of $k_1$ that satisfies the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
k_1\vert x\vert + k_2 > \vert x + k_3\vert \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $k_2 > \vert k3 \vert > 0$, $k_1 \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I have tried to approach this problem using triangle inequality as follows:

1. **CASE 1:**
   \begin{align}
   k_1\vert x \vert + \vert k_3 \vert &> \vert x \vert + k_2 > \vert x + k_3 \vert \tag{2}\\
   \Rightarrow k_1 &> \frac{\vert k_3 \vert - k_2}{\vert x \vert} + 1 \tag{3}
   \end{align}
2. **CASE 2:**
   \begin{align}
   \vert x \vert + \vert k_3 \vert > k_1\vert x \vert + k_2 > \vert x + k_2 \vert
   \end{align}

- The left side inequality gives $\frac{\vert k_2 \vert - k_3}{\vert x \vert} + 1 > k_1$.
- However, I get stuck with the upper limit inequality. How do I proceed with this calculation?

Comment: should $(1)$ hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or should be at least one  $x \in \mathbb{R}$  that $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Try conditioning on the 3 ranges based on the signage of the expression in the absolute value. $\quad$ For case 1, how is $ |x| + |k_3| > |x| + k_2$, esp since we are given that $k_2 > |k_3|$?

Comment: @miracle173 at least one $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin there was an error there as you pointed out. fixed it.

Comment: @FullMetal "*at least one $x$*" $\;-\;$ Any $k_1$ satisfies the inequality for $x=0$.